# Switching to Python 2.7 in Cloud9-IDE

Tags: python-2.7, symlink, python-2.6, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to change default python version to 2.7 in Cloud 9-IDE. I have managed to install correct version with command: `nada-nix install python-2.7.4`

It installs the version nicely, but default version stays 2.6.6.

```
$ python --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Python 2.6.6
```

I have tried to update symbolic link to the correct version. But it says that I'm not privileged enough.

```
ln -nsf /usr/bin/python2.7.4  /usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                            
ln: cannot remove `/usr/bin/python': Permission denied
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud9 package manager will install the python version 2.7 into `~/.nada-nix-profile/bin/python2.7`. This is in your path so you can execute `python2.7` from the terminal. If you want to symlink this to `python` just execute

`$ ln -s ~/.nada-nix-profile/bin/python2.7 ~/.nada-nix-profile/bin/python`

Afterwards you might have to close and reopen the terminal to activate the new version. Also the run button will then use python 2.7.